# Rspec is not working with mongodb, mongomapper

Tags: mongodb, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

My class

```
class Review
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
  key :user_name, String, :require => true
  key :user_avatar, String, :require => true
end
```

Rspec code

```
  it "when user name is not present" do
    blank = FactoryGirl.build(:review, user_name: nil)
    blank.should_not be_valid
  end
```

Why does it raises this error?

```
 1) Review when user name is not present
         Failure/Error: blank.should_not be_valid
           expected #<Review _id: BSON::ObjectId('5236d401ebe86612fe000006'), user_avatar: "#<Avatar:0xb60083c>")> not to be valid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the details you have provided I hope you are going to do validation testing. So problem is validation is not checked at model level. may be this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758595/rails-3-1-rspec-creating-test-case-validate-field-for-model) will direct you properly.

There is syntax problem. you should use `required` rather than `require`. So now the new code should be looks like this :

```
class Review
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
  key :user_name, String, :required => true
  key :user_avatar, String, :required => true
end
```

Please go through this documentation for more details :

http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/validations.html

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: They are testing like me, it is so strange, Factory.build(:contact, lastname: nil).should_not be_valid - See more at: http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/19/testing-series-rspec-models-factory-girl.html#sthash.KjxtOUfE.dpuf